# Nginx Host header for upstream

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx and I have problem setting a reverse proxy.

My nginx.conf is default (didn't make any change to it) and my site-available config is:

```
upstream backend_hosts {
    server server1.example.com
    server server2.example.com
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend_hosts;
    }
}
```

and it's not working, it doesn't pass the host header. When i do something like this, it works:

```
...

proxy_set_header Host server1.exampple.com;

...
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
proxy_set_header Host $current_upstream_server_name;
```

Comment: What value do you want to use? `server{1,2}.example.com`? If so, have you tried `$proxy_host` instead of `$host`?

Comment: I want it to be set to the one chosen by the upstream, I have tried $proxy_host and it's not working as well.

Comment: Huh. Ok, could you clarify how exactly it's "not working"? Header is not set, is empty or something else?

Comment: Well, it's only working when i write the name of the upstream server directly as I stated in my post, when i set header to server1.example.com it works, if i set it to $host or $proxy_host it returns 404 error.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately I don't think there's a clean solution. I've tried your setup and for me `$host` contains original value from the request, while `$proxy_host` is set to `"backend_hosts"`. Also, I found a similar question at ServerFault which may (or may not) help: http://serverfault.com/questions/598202/make-nginx-to-pass-hostname-of-the-upstream-when-reverseproxying

Comment: I need my Host to be set to actual name of current upstream server. It seems nginx can't do this for me.

Comment: Have you tried the `$host` header when defining the `server_name` directive? Unless you've built NGINX with SNI, it won't automatically extract the host from the URL.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? looks like nginx cant do such a simple thing lol

Answer (score 2):

We've also bee struggling with this problem, and whilst not a complete answer I believe this might help future users landing on this page.

It is possible to write the IP address of the selected upstream server by access the upstream variable `$upstream_http_name`.

```
http {
    upstream backend {
        server server1.example.com;
        server server2.example.com;
    }
    
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $upstream_http_name;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
    }
}
```

If, as in our application, receiving the IP acceptable then the above configuration will pass that information into the Host header of the proxied request.

A full list of the variable provided by the upstream module can be found [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_addr)

Comment: By the link is written:
$upstream_http_name
keep server **response** header fields.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work. After checking the logs, value of `upstream_http_name` is always empty for some reason.